# Rails: Will amended commit be updated when deploying through Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I'm having problem in deploying my rails app, and I have to constantly modify some files and then push to github. These commits are just tweaks, for example, I may try to change the line seperator to see if it help to resolve my deploy problem.

I think it is unnecessary to make these tweaks as new commits. Rather, I'd like to `git commit --amend` and then `push -f origin master`. But since there is no new commit, will the VPS fetch these amended updates? Or it just thinks it is still the same old commit and not update consequently?

BTW: where is the code states that "the github repo get updated? let's fetch it", I didn't find it in my `deploy.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Capistrano pulls down the entire code base whenever you deploy. It doesn't do a `git pull`.It does a `git clone` and your older version goes to releases folder. So you don't have to worry in your case.

Also, When you amend something to a commit that is already pushed to remote, it becomes a new commit with new commit hash. This is generally not a good practice because it will cause problems for others who pulled down the commits before you did the amend.

Comment: If I got company then I woundn't be stuck in the deployment problem now. LOL